# merge 3 dataframes into 1

Tags: python, pandas

I've 3 dataframe like this:

Dataframe 1:

```
Hours | Country | Event
----------------------- 
02:00 |   BR    | Sleeping
09:00 |   GB    | Breakfast
09:30 |   IT    | Meeting
12:00 |   CA    | Lunch Time
15:00 |   RU    | Working
16:00 |   CO    | Salsa Dance
18:00 |   CN    | Happy Hour
21:00 |   US    | Easter
22:00 |   FR    | Shopping
```

Dataframe 2:

```
Hours | Country | Event 
-----------------------
02:00 |   BR    | Sleeping
09:00 |   GB    | Breakfast
09:30 |   IT    | Meeting
15:00 |   RU    | Working
16:00 |   CO    | Salsa Dance
18:00 |   CN    | Happy Hour
```

Dataframe 3:

```
Hours | Country | Event
----------------------- 
02:00 |   BR    | Sleeping
09:30 |   IT    | Meeting
16:00 |   CO    | Salsa Dance
```

What im trying to obtain is a fourth dataframe where count everytime a row is repeated and save the value in a new row.

So should looks something like this:

Dataframe 4:

```
Hours | Country | Event        | Count 
--------------------------------------
02:00 |   BR    | Sleeping     |   3
09:00 |   GB    | Breakfast    |   2
09:30 |   IT    | Meeting      |   3
12:00 |   CA    | Lunch Time   |   1
15:00 |   RU    | Working      |   2
16:00 |   CO    | Salsa Dance  |   3
18:00 |   CN    | Happy Hour   |   2
21:00 |   US    | Easter       |   1
22:00 |   FR    | Shopping     |   1
```

Any suggestion to do this using pandas? i tried some For loops nested but something dosen't works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all your dataframes into a single one and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to add the "Count" column:

```
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
         .groupby(['Hours', 'Country', 'Event'], as_index=False)
         .agg(Count=('Event', 'size'))
      )
```

Or with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
         .value_counts(sort=False).reset_index(name='Count')
      )
```

Output:

```
   Hours Country        Event  Count
0  02:00      BR     Sleeping      3
1  09:00      GB    Breakfast      2
2  09:30      IT      Meeting      3
3  12:00      CA   Lunch Time      1
4  15:00      RU      Working      2
5  16:00      CO  Salsa Dance      3
6  18:00      CN   Happy Hour      2
7  21:00      US       Easter      1
8  22:00      FR     Shopping      1
```